# Blazor Web Assembly App Deployment and Updates

Tags: blazor, single-page-application, webassembly

We are completing our first enterprise level stand alone (Not Hosted on .Net Core) Blazor WASM app. In our app we have a flyout navigation menu where you need to click on a button for it to display for smaller mobile screens. This works fine... but for whatever reason, it seems we always have to do a browser refresh to get the flyout navigation button to work after the initial download. It wasn't that big a deal in development once we figured it out... but now that we are ready to release to production it is not ideal.

The question is, is there an event that gets fired after **everything** gets downloaded? Since it takes a while for everything to download Blazor displays pieces of the UI as quickly as possible but in this case we are not fully ready to go interactive until everything is downloaded since it doesn't work properly until everything is downloaded. You don't want to have to tell your users: "you will have to refresh the screen after you login"! My idea is to just display a pre-loader screen until everything gets downloaded so at least the app is fully functional.

In the same spirit we were looking for a more fluid way to handle app updates for WASM. From a deployment standpoint Blazor caches the old version of the app to the point to where you need to clear the browser history every time you want to push an update. On a desktop I guess it isn't that big a deal to hit Ctrl + F5. But on a mobile device that doesn't work. In either case, you don't want to have to again explain to your users additional steps that they will need to perform to get fully updated.

Comment: have you considered the "OnAfterRender" lifecycle hook for this? no code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hard one as I didn't know the real cause of the issue and since our team is new to Blazor we didn't understand how to word the issue either. My explanation above is what I had assumed to be the case but was not the cause.

Turned out the issue was our invocation of the JavaScript libraries. The hard part was the way we were doing it worked... but only after refreshing the page for some crazy reason. However after watching a tutorial on Pluralsight: "JavaScript Interop in Blazor Applications" I experimented by invoking the JavaScript from within the .js file instead of invoking the file itself from C# and this seemed to bring it how to work as it should.

This may be one of those "one off's" but I am documenting it here in case anyone else has similar issues and is new to Blazor like we are.

Answer (score 1):

No code shown in your original question, but you could possibly use the `OnAfterRender` lifecycle hook to answer the loading issue. If you start with your screen in a loading state, you can do something like this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)

    // execute conditionally for loading data, otherwise this will load
    // every time the page refreshes
    if(firstRender)
    {
        // Break UI logic free from async task execution

        await Task.Delay(1);

        // Do work to load page data and set properties
        // Long running tasks like data fetch and so on can be placed here
        
        await ...

        // Then reset a flag that will switch the 
        // page to it's running (loaded) state and call StatHasChanged()
        // Your loading flags will differ, however you see fit to implement
        
        PageState.IsLoading = false;
        

         // Use InvokeAsync method with await to make sure 
         // StateHasChanged runs correctly here without interfering with another
         // thread and synchronizes back to correct context 

         await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    }
}
```

The key point here is that you have a chance to get a responsive app running and show a loading spinner, make links work, etc. but still do background execution using task patterns, and then when it's all done you reset the loading flag and make the async call to ``StateHasChanged``` and show the functional application. The user has to wait for initialization code to complete, but will be aware that the application is loading and have the chance to interact to a small degree.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did not add any code because basically there was nothing that we are currently implementing to show code for. It is a Blazor app as described. When I was speaking of the Preloader I basically meant the "Loading..." that comes on the base Blazor template. We are not performing any running tasks or anything... the app is just doing the initial download. I am not sure how to implement this with the standard loading screen but will do some research. So far I have not found much documentation on this.

Comment: While this did not end up resolving this issue... after examining and researching your code a bit more it helped me resolve another issue I was having in a drop down that wouldn't fully populate after the page was loaded so +1 and thanks!